# Angular 2 Router Wildcard handling with child-routes

Tags: angular

When using child routes with angular2's router "3.0", there is no need to declare them in the parent router config (before, you had to do something like `/child...` in the parent component).

I want to configure a global "page not found" handler, which I can do like this:

```
{ path: '**', component: PageNotFoundComponent }
```

in my app routing module.

The caveat: If I do this, the router navigates to routes declared in the app routing module before the `PageNotFoundComponent` just fine. But it always navigates to the wildcard route when I try to access a child route (declared using `RouterModule.forChild` in some child routing module.

Intuitively, the wildcard route should be placed behind all other route configs, because the router resolves in declaration order. But there does not seem to be a way to declare it after the child routes. It also does not seem very elegant to declare a wildcard route in all child router modules.

Am I missing something or is there just no way to define a global 404-page in Angular-2-Router-3 when using child routes?

Comment: Today (version 5) it seems not be a case any more. The more specific paths seem to be matched before trying less specific, no matter the order of declaration.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

You can easily have a centralized wildcard route, i.e. for a site-wide 'Page not found' component. It simply has to be extracted into a **separate routing module**, which gets included **after all the other modules** containing child routes.

Therefore, the wildcard route is truly in last position and doesn't hide the routes from any following module.

#### The wildcard routing module or 'page not found' routing module:

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [
        RouterModule.forChild([
            {
                path: '**',
                component: NotFoundComponent
            }
        ])
    ],
    declarations: [
        NotFoundComponent
    ],
    exports: [
        RouterModule
    ]
})
export class WildcardRoutingModule { }
```

#### The application module :

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,

        AppRoutingModule, // Has forRoot routes 

        HomeModule, // Has forChild routes 
        LoginModule, // Has forChild routes
        ProductModule, // Has forChild routes
        DiagnosticsModule, // Has forChild routes

        WildcardRoutingModule // Last position
    ],
    declarations: [
        AppComponent  
    ],
    providers: [
    ],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {
}
```

Comment: One little thing: The `NotFoundComponent` has to be `declared` somewhere. I did that in the 'page not found' routing module.

Comment: neat! I was also trying to figure this out. I realized based on this solution, an alternative way to do it is to just import the AppRoutingModule after all the child modules.

Comment: @David: Just added it to the WildcardRoutingModule.

Comment: Thanks @David I really like you! Best question ever and now best comment ever too :)

Comment: Does path: '**' covers path:'' ?

Comment: @MathieuRenda - What to do for lazy loaded modules ?

Answer (score 24):

Simple solution is to reorder modules in the 'imports' array in app module file - ensure app/root router is the last item in the array; for example

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [FeatureModule1, FeatureModule2, FeatureModule3, AppRouterModule]
  ...
  ...
})
```

Comment: Even with this, i still got app routing config sits above feature routing configs.

Comment: Yeap, order is important

Answer (score 2):

I have the following example for you. The `/`-route redirects to the `/app`-route and shows the `StartComponent` inside the `<router-outlet>` of your parent `AppComponent`. The `StartComponent` itself has another `<router-outlet>` in its template in which the router loads the child components.

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
    {
        path: '',
        redirectTo: 'app',
        pathMatch: 'full',
    },
    {
        path: 'app',
        component: StartComponent,
        children: [
            {
                path: '',
                redirectTo: 'welcome'
            },
            {
                path: 'welcome',
                component: WelcomeComponent
            },
            {
                path: 'settings',
                component: SettingsComponent
            },            
        ]
    },
    {
        path: '**',
        component: PageNotFoundComponent 
    }    
];
```

The last route is the wildcard route with the `**`-path. It will be shown if you navigate to a not known URL like `/test123` or for the child components `/app/test123`.

The `pathMatch: 'full'` means that the router is looking for a equal route. It is important for the redirects.

If you also need a `PageNotFoundComponent` for your children, you can add a wildcard to them too.

```
{
    path: 'app',
    component: StartComponent,
    children: [
        {
            path: '',
            redirectTo: 'welcome'
        },
        {
            path: 'welcome',
            component: WelcomeComponent
        },    
        {
            path: '**',
            component: ChildrenPageNotFoundComponent
        },      
    ]
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. What you describe is not exactly the case I had in mind - I was thinking of the example in Milestone #4 on https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html. They have routes defined in the `crisis-center-routing.module.ts`, but none in the `app-routing.module.ts`. I would like to define the global 404 handler in the app routing module.

Comment: I need this as well, as my feature modules define their own routes.

Comment: Does path: '**' covers path:'' ?