# No component factory found for undefined. but did add to @NgModule.entryComponents with SharedModule

Tags: angular, angular-components, angular-module, angular-cli-v6

So I've found dozens of articles explaining this problem and most suggestions say to add my component to the entryComponents array in @NgModule, but I am stumped as to where or which entryComponents in the many modules I have.. so basically my Module dependencies look like:

```
AppModule
 - EnvironmentModule
 - ContainerModule
 - SharedModule

EnvironmentModule
 - ContainerModule
 - EnvironmentListItemDetailComponent
    private _dialogRef: MatDialogRef<ConfirmDialogComponent>;

ContainerModule
 - MatDialogModule, 
 - ConfirmDialogComponent (this is the component that I want to move)
 - ContainerListItemDetailComponent
     private _dialogRef: MatDialogRef<ConfirmDialogComponent>;
```

Basically I want to move the ConfirmDialogComponent from the nested child Module to a shared Module that both the Environment and Container modules can take a dependency on. (I'd also love to move the ContainerModule out from under the EnvironmentModule, but that's for another day)

So I want to move ConfirmDialogComponent into a SharedModule and get everything hooked up, what do the @NgModule for App, Environment, Container, Shared look like? I am really confused.. so here's what I have so far:

shared.module.ts:

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    MatDialogModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule
  ],
  declarations: [
    ConfirmDialogComponent
  ],
  exports: [
    ConfirmDialogComponent
  ],
  entryComponents: [
    ConfirmDialogComponent
  ]
})
export class SharedModule { }
```

environment.module.ts:

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    HttpClientModule,
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    EnvironmentRoutingModule,
    ContainerModule
  ],
  declarations: [
    EnvironmentListComponent,
    EnvironmentListEnvironmentsComponent,
    EnvironmentListItemDetailComponent,
    EnvironmentListItemComponent
  ],
  providers: [... ]
})
```

container.module.ts:

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    FormsModule,
    CommonModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    MatDialogModule,
    ContainerRoutingModule
  ],
  declarations: [
    KeysPipe,
    ContainerListComponent,
    ContainerListItemComponent,
    ContainerListItemDetailComponent,
    ParameterListComponent,
    ParameterListItemComponent,
    ParameterTypeInfoComponent,
    ConfirmDialogComponent
  ],
  exports: [
    ContainerListComponent
  ],
  providers: [...],
  entryComponents: [ ConfirmDialogComponent ]
})
```

app.module.ts:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    FormsModule,
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    HttpModule,
    ContainerModule,
    EnvironmentModule,
    LoginModule,
    SharedModule,
    PageNotFoundModule /* DO NOT MOVE THIS - as a result of routing peculiarities the order of child routes matter for handling wildcard ** https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40015385/angular-2-router-wildcard-handling-with-child-routes */
  ],
  providers: [
    AppConfigService,
    AuthGuardService,
    BootstrapService,
    EventBrokerService,
    HttpClientService,
    TruIdTokenService,
    StartupService,
    {
      provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
      useFactory: initConfiguration,
      deps: [StartupService],
      multi: true
    }
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
```

So I don't know :\ it's a bit of a mess and I am not even sure I have all my dependencies organized correctly.

Comment: Just remove the entry component(ConfirmDialogComponent ) from your sub modules such as **ContainerModule** and **EnvironmentModule** , I think it will work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Remove all entry `entryComponents`
2. Remove the declaration of `ConfirmDialogComponent` from all modules except `SharedModule`.
3. Import `SharedModule` into the modules wherever `ConfirmDialogComponent` was used.

Comment: Nope.. 

RROR Error: No component factory found for ConfirmDialogComponent. Did you add it to @NgModule.entryComponents?

EnvironmentListItemDetailComponent.push../src/app/environment/environment-list-item-detail/environment-list-item-detail.component.ts.EnvironmentListItemDetailComponent.confirmSave (environment-list-item-detail.component.ts:192)
    at Object.eval [as handleEvent] (EnvironmentListItemDetailComponent.html:34)
    at handleEvent (core.js:10251)
    at callWithDebugContext (core.js:11344)

Comment: Import the `SharedModule` into the `Module` of `environment-list-item-detail.component.ts`

Comment: Yea I did that:

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    HttpClientModule,
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    EnvironmentRoutingModule,
    ContainerModule,
    SharedModule
  ],
  declarations: [
    EnvironmentListComponent,
    EnvironmentListEnvironmentsComponent,
    EnvironmentListItemDetailComponent,
    EnvironmentListItemComponent
  ],

Comment: Fixed it! I had to add   entryComponents: [
    ConfirmDialogComponent
  ] to the SharedModule, and then idiotically i forgot to change the component import of the child imports:

import { ConfirmDialogComponent } from '../../shared/confirm-dialog/confirm-dialog.component';

Answer (score 3):

So I guess I needed:

1. Remove all entry `entryComponents`
2. Remove the declaration of `ConfirmDialogComponent` from all modules except `SharedModule`.
3. Import `SharedModule` into the modules wherever `ConfirmDialogComponent` was used.
4. Add `entryComponents: [ ConfirmDialogComponent ]` to the `SharedModule`
5. Change `import { ConfirmDialogComponent }` in any child component to use the new location of the shared component