# Routes not working in angular for feature module

Tags: angular

I am trying to create a new feature `module` in angular. I have setup new routing for the feature module, but the routes defined here are not working.

My feature module is `WSmodule`.

**wsmodule.routing.module.ts**

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
    {
        path: "workspace", component: WSHomeComponent
    }
];

@NgModule({
    imports: [RouterModule.forChild(appRoutes)],
    exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class WsModuleRoutingModule {}
```

**wsmodule.module.ts**

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    WsModuleRoutingModule
  ],
  declarations: [WSHomeComponent]
})
export class WSModuleModule { }
```

**app.routing.module.ts**

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [

    { path: "", component: HomeComponent },

    {
       path: "notfound", component: NotFoundComponent
    },
    {
        path: "**", redirectTo: '/notfound'
    }
];

@NgModule({
    imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes)],
    exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

**app.module.ts**

```
imports[
    WSModuleModule,
    AppRoutingModule
]
```

Now when I try to open the url `http://localhost:4200/workspace`, it gets redirected to `http://localhost:4200/notfound`. It means my `wsmodule` routes are not being recognized.

Comment: did you find any solution to this problem besides doing lazy loading?

Answer (score 2):

The wild card routes does not work in the root Module. You need to create a separate routing module for that and load it last

ws-home.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';


@Component({
    templateUrl: './ws-home.component.html',
})
export class WSHomeComponent
{
}
```

wsmodule.routing.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';

import { WSHomeComponent } from './ws-home.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  {   path: 'workspace',   component: WSHomeComponent   },
];

@NgModule({
    imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
    exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class WsModuleRoutingModule { }
```

wsmodule.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';


import { WsModuleRoutingModule } from './wsmodule.routing.module';
import { WSHomeComponent } from './ws-home.component';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [WSHomeComponent],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    WsModuleRoutingModule
  ],
  providers: [],
})
export class WSModuleModule { }
```

wildcard-routing.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { NotfoundComponent } from './notfound.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'notfound',   component:NotfoundComponent },
  { path: '**', redirectTo:'/notfound' }

];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class WildcardRoutingModule { }
```

app-routing.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { HomeComponent } from './home.component';


const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '',   component:HomeComponent },
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

app.module.ts

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { WildcardRoutingModule} from './wildcard-routing.module';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HomeComponent} from './home.component';
import { NotfoundComponent} from './notfound.component';

import { WSModuleModule} from './feature1';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,HomeComponent,NotfoundComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    WSModuleModule, 
    WildcardRoutingModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Refer to this answer

[Angular 2 Router Wildcard handling with child-routes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40015385/angular-2-router-wildcard-handling-with-child-routes)

[Angular Router](https://www.tektutorialshub.com/routing-navigation-in-angular/)
[Wild card routes](https://www.tektutorialshub.com/routing-navigation-in-angular/#Wild-Card-Route)

Comment: Thanks, but now I get the following error when I try to navigate to /workspace.
`Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'workspace'`. Also, not for any random url, it is not redirecting me to `/notfound`.

Comment: Thanks, but it is not able to find the route `workspace` itself. I removed the wildcard route entirely, and I still get the following error: `Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'workspace'`

Comment: did you create wildcardroutingmodule.ts ?

Comment: No, I just removed the wildcard route from the app.routing.module.ts. Since, I no longer have the wildcard route, the issue I think is something else. It is not able to find `workspace` route.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need to lazy loading, you can simply reference the `wsmodule.module.ts` in the app module.

Here is a little example : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nnqwum

Be careful with your dependencies :

In `wsmodule.routing.module.ts`, check if you have

```
import { WSHomeComponentComponent } from './wshome-component/wshome-component.component';``
```

In `wsmodule.module.ts`, check if you have :

```
import { WSHomeComponentComponent } from './wshome-component/wshome-component.component';
import { WsModuleRoutingModule } from './wsmodule.routing.module';
```

And in `app.module.ts`, check if you have imported the module `wsmodule.module.ts`:

```
import { WsmoduleModule } from './wsmodule/wsmodule.module';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';

@NgModule({
  imports:      [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    WsmoduleModule,
    AppRoutingModule
  ]...
```

Comment: Thanks, but what is the change in the above example from the code in the question. I am sorry but I am not able to find any change here.

Comment: Can you please check the dependencies because I don't find any error in the routes.

Answer (score 0):

It is because you have not specified any route which will load your Feature module `(WSModule)`. When you specify routing in a feature module, you generally lazy load it by using the `loadChildren` property in your routes at root level.

Comment: Thanks, could you please give an example for the same?

Comment: I would suggest a read through of angular docs for better understanding https://angular.io/guide/lazy-loading-ngmodules

Answer (score 0):

here is  app.routing.module.ts

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
    {
        path: '',
        component: HomeComponent,
        data: {
            title: 'Home'
        },
        children: [
            {
                path: 'ws',
                loadChildren: '.<path to WsModuleRoutingModule >#WsModuleRoutingModule '
            },
        ],
    },
    {
        path: "notfound", component: NotFoundComponent
    },
    {
        path: "**", redirectTo: '/notfound'
    }
];
```

here is wsmodule.routing.module.ts

```
const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: "",
        data: {
            title: "Ws"
        },
        children: [
            {
                path: "workspace",
                component: WSHomeComponent,
                data: {
                    title: "WS"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

you can access this Via

```
http://localhost:4200/#/ws/workspace
```

Comment: i have edit the routes for lazy loading. now check it out