# Angular 2+ Conditional wildcard redirect

Tags: angular

I have different routes, each representing a step in a wizard.

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: ':id',
    component: ParentComponent,
    children: [
      {path: 'step1', component: Step1Component},
      {path: 'step2', component: Step2Component},
      {path: 'step3', component: Step3Component},
      {path: 'step4', component: Step4Component},
      {path: '**', redirectTo: '???'}
    ]
  }
];
```

Now I want to have a conditional `redirectTo` such that when a user is in step 3 and access the root url, he will be redirected to step 3.

An example of the logic I want to execute on the redirect:

```
if(this.stepService.getCurrentStep(id) === 3) {
  return 'step3';
} else {
  return 'step1';
}
```

**HOWEVER** all routes should still be accessible, such that when a user goes to rout /step2 or /step4 he is not redirected to step 3. 
I think a canActivate guard is thus not applicable.

I was thinking of creating an additional component to handle the redirect but it seems a bit too

Comment: Possible [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40015385/angular-2-router-wildcard-handling-with-child-routes)

Comment: The use case is different as in that question a use wants to use a global wildcard, while here the question is to have a wildcard that redirects to different pages on a given condition.

Comment: could you please expand a little bit more your redirectoTo logic? Maybe some more examples?

Comment: I've updated the question. In short I want to check in which step of the flow a given entity is and then redirect to that step.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out how to solve this.

You can add a canActivate guard on the wildcard route:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: ':id',
    component: ParentComponent,
    children: [
      {path: 'step1', component: Step1Component},
      ...
      {path: '**', canActivate:[RedirectGuard]}
    ]
  }
];
```

Then in the guard you should return an UrlTree instead of a boolean:

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class RedirectGuard implements CanActivate {

  constructor(private stepService: StepService) {}

   canActivate(
     next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
     state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<UrlTree> {
     const id = next.parent.params.id;
     // Some logic  
     return of(this.router.parseUrl(state.url + '/rejection'));
  }
}
```

Note that this solution requires angular 7.1+

Credits go to this blogpost: https://juristr.com/blog/2018/11/better-route-guard-redirects/