# How to combine routes in different modules in an Angular application

Tags: angular, typescript

In the application I would like to combine two sets of routes. Both defined in different modules.

There's the first module:

**./app-routing.module.ts**

```
import {NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import {Routes, RouterModule} from '@angular/router';
import {UserDashboardComponent} from './user-dashboard/containers/user-dashboard/user-dashboard.component';
import {NotFoundComponent} from './not-found/not-found.component';

const ROUTES: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: UserDashboardComponent, pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: '**', component: NotFoundComponent, pathMatch: 'full' },
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(ROUTES)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

And here the second:

**./auth.module.ts**

```
import {NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import {CommonModule} from '@angular/common';
import {RouterModule, Routes} from '@angular/router';
import {LoginComponent} from './login/containers/login-view/login-view.component';
import {RegisterComponent} from './register/containers/register-view/register-view.component';

export const ROUTES: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'auth',
    children: [
      { path: '', pathMatch: 'full', redirectTo: 'login' },
      { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
      { path: 'register', component: RegisterComponent },
    ],
  },
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(ROUTES)
  ],
})
export class AuthModule {}
```

And the part where they should come together is:

**./app.module.ts**

```
import {BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser';
import {NgModule} from '@angular/core';

import {AuthModule} from '../auth/auth.module';

import {AppRoutingModule} from './app-routing.module';
import {UserDashboardModule} from './user-dashboard/user-dashboard.module';

import {AppComponent} from './app.component';
import {NotFoundComponent} from './not-found/not-found.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    NotFoundComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule, // main routes
    AuthModule, // authorization module which also has routes
    UserDashboardModule,
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
  exports: [NotFoundComponent],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

And in my app.component.ts:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: `
    <div class="app">
      <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    </div>
  `,
})

export class AppComponent {}
```

But I am only seeing the routes from 'app-routing.module.ts' somehow. What do I have to do to also be able to use the ones from auth?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In **./auth.module.ts** try using

```
RouterModule.forChild(ROUTES)
```

instead of

```
RouterModule.forRoot(ROUTES)
```

Comment: That makes sense. "reates a module with all the router directives and a provider registering routes.". Yet it's not working. Is there something else missing? Something with providers by any chance?

Comment: When I remove `{ path: '**', component: NotFoundComponent, pathMatch: 'full' }` I do see a different result. So maybe those double asterisks route is interfering.

Comment: Yep, apparently that is an issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40015385/angular-2-router-wildcard-handling-with-child-routes 
The route that will lead to "page not found" (or component) has to be the last. I assume that the child routes are placed after the root one and therefore are never reached.
You can see some solutions to this in the link above.

Comment: Ah, great. Thanks for this. I've used forChild, and moved the wildcard to a separate route module which is included last. Now when I navigate to http://localhost:4200/auth I see it being redirected to /auth/login, but then immediately redirects again to http://localhost:4200 and get the error: `NullInjectorError: R3InjectorError(AppModule)[LoginService -> LoginService -> LoginService]:`

Comment: If you are using a custom service (LoginService) you should specify it into the providers array of **app.module.ts**. Other option would be annotating the service with `@Injectable({providedIn: 'root'})`

Comment: Oké. Found out adding `exports: [LoginModule, RegisterModule],` to auth.module.ts also solves this issue.